# change content order when changing orientation with auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, swift4

I wonder how I can achieve the following with auto layouts in Swift 4 in the story board:

I have a quadratic collection view. In portrait mode, this should be on top filling the entire width and having a height equal to the width. Other controls should then be below it.

In landscape mode, the quadratic view should be on the left, having the height of the landscape and an equal width, thus again being quadratic. Now, other controls should be on the right.

Naturally, the behavior is the opposite: the order of controls is always top -> bottom, no matter the orientation. But for me it is crucial that the quadratic collection view fills as most of the screen as possible.

How can I achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In XCode10, first set all your constraints, e.g. in portrait mode. Then switch to landscape mode. One can click afterwards click on `"View as: iPhone ..."`, an area will pop up with some button `"Vary for Traits"`.

In the dialog, we can choose to vary based on "Width" (= Landscape) or "Height" (= Portrait), which means that we can define a distinct set of constraints for the orientation that we have so far *not* utilized.

In the end, we have two set of constraints each for landscape and portrait mode.

This quite extensive tutorial explains more on it: https://www.raywenderlich.com/492-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started